# visual basic simple calculator

Tags: visual-studio, vba, global-variables

I wrote simple calculator with visual basic but when I debug my code, it has problem and dose not run correctly .

my code

```
Public Sub general()

Dim num1 As Long, num2 As Long
Dim result As Single
Dim op As String

End Sub

Private Sub Form_Load()
Text1 = " "
num1 = "0"
num2 = "0"
op = " "
one.Caption = "1"
two.Caption = "2"
three.Caption = "3"
four.Caption = "4"
five.Caption = "5"
six.Caption = "6"
seven.Caption = "7"
eight.Caption = "8"
nine.Caption = "9"
zero.Caption = "0"
clear11.Caption = "cls"
Equal12.Caption = "="
plus.Caption = "+"
min14.Caption = "-"
multi15.Caption = "*"
div16.Caption = "/"
lnx17.Caption = "1/x"
power18.Caption = "x^2"
arc19.Caption = "aqr(x)"
exit20.Caption = "Exit"

End Sub

Private Sub one_Click()
Text1 = Text1 + "1"

End Sub
Private Sub two_Click()
Text1 = Text1 + "2"

End Sub
Private Sub three_Click()
Text1 = Text1 + "3"

End Sub
Private Sub four_Click()
Text1 = Text1 + "4"

End Sub
Private Sub five_Click()
Text1 = Text1 + "5"

End Sub
Private Sub six_Click()
Text1 = Text1 + "6"

End Sub
Private Sub seven_Click()
Text1 = Text1 + "7"

End Sub
Private Sub eight_Click()
Text1 = Text1 + "8"

End Sub
Private Sub nine_Click()
Text1 = Text1 + "9"

End Sub
Private Sub zero_Click()
Text1 = Text1 + "0"

End Sub

Private Sub clear11_click() 'cls button
test1 = ""
num1 = "0"
num2 = "0"
op = ""

End Sub


Private Sub Equal12_click() 'Equal button

num2 = Val(Text1)
Select Case op
Case "+"
result = num1 + num2
Case "-"
result = num1 - num2
Case "*"
result = num1 * num2
Case "/"
result = num1 / num2
Case "1/x"
result = 1 / num1
Case "x^2"
result = num1 ^ 2
'Case "aqr(x)"
'result = aqr(num1)

End Select
Text1 = Str(result)
op = ""

End Sub
Private Sub plus_click()
num1 = Val(Text1)
op = "+"
Text1 = ""

End Sub
Private Sub min14_click()
num1 = Val(Text1)
op = "-"
Text1 = ""

End Sub
Private Sub multi15_click()
num1 = Val(Text1)
op = "*"
Text1 = ""

End Sub
Private Sub div16_click()
num1 = Val(Text1)
op = "/"
Text1 = ""

End Sub

Private Sub squareroot19_click() 'sqr(x)button
num1 = Val(Text)
result = Sqr(num1)
Text1 -Str(result)

End Sub
```

when I debug it I find the problem is "op" variable that not set in correct way because when I click on equal button and the program go to select case part the value of "op" is empty.
can any one help me how to fix it?

Comment: @Reisclef op is operand and use for know what is the operand user click on it and use it in the plus_click() , multi15_click() and other part.

Comment: I see now, thanks. You probably want a function to run when each key is pressed to check if op is populated. If it's not, then the button should be disabled. Either that, or include an else statement in the equal function to do nothing if the op is a blank.

Comment: @Reisclef when I want to calculate 1+5 then plus_click() part put "+" string in to op but when I click on the = button op value become empty. I can find where is the problem. op is global variable so it must not have problem like this

Comment: Okay, I understand. So what happens? Do you get an error message? Or is it a logical error with what is output? If it's an error, can you include that in the post?

Comment: @Reisclef it dose not give any error just after I run 1+5 the result it gives me is 0

Answer (score 0):

I've run the following in a single function and it seems to work for me. I get 3 when running the code within the methods to click 1, click +, and click 2.

I basically put the output of this into a textbox on a windows form, which displayed 3 when I ran this code.

I did add the line **Dim text1 As String**, did you declare this elsewhere?

```
Dim num1 As Long, num2 As Long
        Dim result As Single
        Dim op As String
        Dim text1 As String

        text1 = " "
        num1 = "0"
        num2 = "0"
        op = " "

        text1 = text1 + "1"


        num1 = Val(text1)
        op = "+"
        text1 = ""

        text1 = text1 + "2"


        num2 = Val(text1)
        Select Case op
            Case "+"
                result = num1 + num2
            Case "-"
                result = num1 - num2
            Case "*"
                result = num1 * num2
            Case "/"
                result = num1 / num2
            Case "1/x"
                result = 1 / num1
            Case "x^2"
                result = num1 ^ 2
                'Case "aqr(x)"
                'result = aqr(num1)

        End Select
        text1 = Str(result)
        op = ""
```

Comment: no I didn't declare it anywhere else , and also when I put all my code in one function it dose not give me answer

Comment: The main reason I put the code into the single method was to test it. Have you tried declaring text1 it as I did above? What kind of object is text1?

Answer (score 0):

Declare your varibles outside the general method. This will make the methods available to get/set them. An alternative could be to pass the buttons value as a parameter, but the first part is the easier!